# How to open a bookmark or bookmarklet in Chrome from batch file

Tags: windows, google-chrome, batch-file, bookmarklet, imacros

I would like to create a batch file that would open a bookmark I have. The bookmark is an imacro which performs a function. I'm using the batch to start the imacro because the batch is compatible with windows task scheduler.  `start "Chrome" chrome --new-window www.google.com`
opens a new window and loads google. I just need to load a bookmark.

Comment: Rather you'll need a html file that redirects to `chrome://bookmarks/`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to launch a bookmark in order to run an Imacros file and probably you don't need to open the google page before launching it (you can go to google from inside imacros script). To launch an imacros script from batch you can do something like [this](http://forum.iopus.com/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=20952&p=54204):

```
start /B "" "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" http://run.imacros.net/?m=YOUR_IMACROS_SCRIPT.iim
```

I didn't test it on Chrome, but should be a similar thing.